# How to return multiple rows with the max value

Tags: mysql, select, max

I'm currently doing a document management system that I'm having a few problems with. I want to be able to select and show each unique document with the highest version number
This is my current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( policyheader.policytitle ), 
               Max(policyrecords.policyversion)    AS maxPolicy, 
               policyrecords.useruploaddate, 
               policyrecords.policydesc, 
               LEFT(policyrecords.whatchanged, 30) AS changes, 
               policyheader.policyref 
FROM   policyrecords 
       INNER JOIN policyheader 
               ON policyrecords.policyref = policyheader.policyref 
GROUP  BY policyrecords.policydesc, 
          policyrecords.policyversion
```

I have also been trying `IN` as well. It is returning this data:

[image]

What I want it to return is this data:

[image]

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function. Apart from that, this is a very frequently asked question. However, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I've added pictures, i'll try using sql fiddle to replicate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this in several ways.  The `not exists` method often performs well:

```
SELECT ph.policyTitle, pr.*
FROM policyrecords pr INNER JOIN
     policyheader ph
     ON pr.policyRef = ph.policyRef
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from policyrecords pr2
                  where pr2.policyRef = pr.policyRef and
                        pr2.policyVersion > pr.policyVersion
                 );
```

This implements the following logic:  "Get me all the records from `policyrecords` where there is no records with the same `policyRef` and a larger `policyVersion`."  This is a fancy way of saying get me the maximum version.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(policyheader.policyTitle),
    MAX(policyrecords.policyVersion) AS maxPolicy,
    policyrecords.userUploadDate,
    policyrecords.policyDesc,
    left(policyrecords.whatChanged,30) as changes,
    policyheader.policyRef
FROM policyrecords
    INNER JOIN policyheader ON policyrecords.policyRef = policyheader.policyRef
GROUP BY
    DISTINCT(policyheader.policyTitle)
```

If you group by version, you will see all the versions for one policyTitle :)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
 policyheader.policyTitle,
 policyrecords.policyVersion,
 policyrecords.userUploadDate,
 policyrecords.policyDesc,
 left(policyrecords.whatChanged,30) as changes,
 policyheader.policyRef
 FROM policyrecords
 INNER JOIN policyheader ON policyrecords.policyRef = policyheader.policyRef
 GROUP BY
 policyrecords.policy
 order by policyrecords.policyVersion desc
```